# Notepad++ text string replace/remove

Tags: text, notepad++

I need to replace a text string but I have no idea how should I do this.
Here is the text:

- "abaci - plural of "abacus",a calculating device; a crown of a column
- abaco - one of the islands of the Bahamas abacs - plural of "abac"
- abada - an early name for the rhinoceros
- abade - an obsolete form of "abode"

etc...

What I want to achieve is :

- "abaci
- abaco
- abada
- abade" ...

How to do this?

Comment: Is this the _only_ set of strings you need to operate on, or are there more?

Comment: There are more, cca 3000 items.  All I need is remove all content from the first word. I.e: "abade - an obsolete form of "abode" > "abade".

Comment: Do you have to do this in Notepad++?  Could you write a Python script instead, for example?

Comment: Thanks BenH, but actually it's not my field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use Notepad++ you should try to use regular expressions in it: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

And I guess the search pattern would be `^([a-z]+).*$` and the replacement would most likely be `\1`.